# How to get selected log from filebeat index by python

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, filebeat, kibana-7

i am using python elasticsearch module to search filebeat log by using using keyword. same as i do in "Kibana Discover" but my search does not return anything.

```
# make sure ES is up and running
import requests
res = requests.get('http://xxxxx:9200')
print(res.content)


# Import Elasticsearch package 
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch 
# Connect to the elastic cluster

es=Elasticsearch([{'host':'xxxxx','port':9200}],timeout=30)
es

es.search(index='*',  body={
  'query': {
    'match': {
      'message': 'SocketTimeoutException',
     }
  }
})

es
```

it should give me log file like this but it does not.

message:14:20:01,387 ERROR [com.yuma.jca.sockets.concox] (default-threads - 37) MessageWork SocketTimeoutException for imei: 0358735075610732-> Read timed out @timestamp:Aug 8, 2019 @ 15:20:01.559 ecs.version:1.0.0

but i get like this, only the print connection

b'{\n  "name" : "kibana",\n  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",\n  "cluster_uuid" : "pspfiiegRre8OOFSsLWIhQ",\n  "version" : {\n    "number" : "7.2.0",\n    "build_flavor" : "default",\n    "build_type" : "deb",\n    "build_hash" : "508c38a",\n    "build_date" : "2019-06-20T15:54:18.811730Z",\n    "build_snapshot" : false,\n    "lucene_version" : "8.0.0",\n    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",\n    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"\n  },\n  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"\n}\n'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the result of elasticsearch query into a variable and print the response data.

```
data = es.search(index='*',  body={
  'query': {
    'match': {
      'message': 'SocketTimeoutException',
     }
  }
})
print(data)
```

Comment: @Alexandreison , Thanks , I have fewq more question related to same one, i will create new post